# Hold off React Render until after request

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that's being loaded with the initial state:

```
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      panel: "deals",
      showExtension: false,
      person: {}

    };
  },
```

And I have this to find a person:

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.findPersonFromBackground();
  },
  findPersonFromBackground: function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "findPerson", email: this.props.currentEmail.from_email }, function(person) {
      this.setState({person: person});
    }.bind(this));
  },
```

So all works fine. If the person is found, I render one thing, and if not, something else.

When the first is found, the view goes from non-found state to found state real fast, since the API calls are pretty quick.

What's the best way to wait to render until that first call comes back?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can handle it is with the enum pattern.  In this code, `this.state.person` is either the loading sentinel, the notFound sentinel, or the actual person.

```js
var status = {loading: {}, notFound: {}};

// ...

getInitialState: function(){
  return {person: status.loading}
},
fetchPerson: function(){
  doFetchPerson(function(person){
    if (person) this.setState({person: person})
    else this.setState({person: status.notFound})
  }.bind(this))
},
render: function(){
  var person = this.state.person)
  if (person === status.loading) ...
  else if (person === status.notFound) ...
  else ...
}
```

Comment: Great feedback. I really like this approach because I think the bind that I was in was that initially setting the `person` to `{}` was the same as if the person was queried and came back not found `{}`. Isolating the 2 based on a different status makes a lot of sense and certainly makes it easier to render the right components to convey that message. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, isn't `status.loading === status.notFound`?

Comment: @brandonhilkert objects are compared by reference, not the contents, so `{} !== {}` and `[] !== []`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

There's no good way to do what you're asking, which is to keep a component from rendering at all until some asynchronous operation that the component initiates completes; the best you can do is use techniques from other answers to this question to render something slightly different in the case that it's not complete.

However, the problem you're actually trying to solve is preventing the brief flash of alternatively-rendered content if the API request starts and the completes very quickly. If you move the asynchronous operation to the *parent* of your component, you can ensure that the async operation completes before you ever even render your child.

If the Chrome runtime requests are consistently fast, this may be fine, but in the general case, it's worth considering what the behavior will be if the async operation takes a longer time to complete.

Comment: You make a good point about timing. I hadn't considered the 95 percentile when API responses are not as snappy. In that case, it would be less than optimal to leave a blank space there until it decided to return. Great points to consider.

Answer (score 1):

Is this more of a design question? You could show a spinner, an empty box, a shapes only preview (like Facebook feed), or nothing at all.

If this is a technical question then return null in render().

Comment: Perhaps a little of both. At least the comments got me thinking of both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need this project: https://github.com/toplan/react-hold

You can use the placeholder to keep the shape of your component.

Comment: would be nice if you can add an example of how to resolve the problem with your project

Comment: These are some examples in the project. See: https://github.com/toplan/react-hold/tree/master/examples